# Converting web.config URL Rewrite rules to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following IIS URL Rewrite rules in `web.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="some-name" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

They work for any subfolder, like this:

#### Case A

web.config and index.php are stored in `folder1/test`:
Request `/folder1/test/some/virtual/12-url` is sent to `folder1/test/index.php`.

#### Case B

web.config and index.php are stored in `folder2/wherever/this`:
Request `/folder2/wherever/this/virtual/12-url` is sent to `folder2/wherever/this/index.php`.

For switching to Apache, how can these rules be rewritten so that
there is no need to update .htaccess whenever the subfolder URL changes?
(The project may be hosted on any subfolder, does not require to be placed in Document Root.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Shows HTTP 500. Log: [core:alert] [pid 3580:tid 884] [client 127.0.0.1:56210] C:/thepath/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters